# Voice Catalog only has one package id:206

Tags: swift, here-api

I am running into a similar issue as described here: https://github.com/heremaps/here-ios-sdk-examples/issues/165

I used to have access to multiple voice packages however since I had to change my appId and key, I only have one voice package in the catalog. Below code was working until I had to change key. The user in the github issue had to contact here customer support to enable it.

```
    let voiceCatalog = NMAVoiceCatalog.sharedInstance()
    voiceCatalog?.delegate
    // gets the list of packages
    voiceCatalog?.update()
    let spanishVoice = voiceCatalog?.voicePackage(withId: 204)
    let englishVoice = voiceCatalog?.voicePackage(withId: 206)

// Since the spanish voice catalog does not exist anymore, this will crash the app.
    print("check for spanish voice--",     voiceCatalog?.installedVoicePackages.contains(spanishVoice!)) 
    if(voiceCatalog?.installedVoicePackages.contains(spanishVoice!) == false){
      print("do installation here")
      voiceCatalog?.installVoicePackage(spanishVoice!)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain why you had to change your app_id and key? Maybe this app_id has different rights assigned?

Comment: The original app_id/key failed and upon investigation it was not there in my projects for some reason. I did have a notice that the email was not confirmed and all keys would be expired after 30 days. So I created new credentials for ios premium sdk.

Comment: Suggesting to contact the HERE team, you should find a button on your account and raise this question.

Comment: I am on the freemium plan and I contacted support via https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you. I was told to go to stackoverflow.

Comment: Would you please provide your login name, we will have a deeper look into your app_id

Comment: djohnson@datechnologies.co Thank you!